# Code take too long to process and has a big memory footprint

Tags: php, algorithm, memory-management, gd, spl

This code executes in 0.8seconds and takes up 22Mb of memory on my machine.

```
   $x=500;
   $y=500;

   $im = imagecreatetruecolor($x,$y);
   $ia=array();
   for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $y; $j++) {
        $r=rand(0,96);
        $g=rand(0,128);
        $b=rand(0,255);
        $ia[$i][$j]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    }
   }
```

What can be done to speed it up, but more importantly lower the memory footprint it eats at any given time.

Comment: You could pre-populate a list of random colors, and choose from those colors, instead of creating a new instance each time. Although, I'm not sure how php's memory allocation and collection works.

Comment: The random colors are not the issue here, that's just some code to fill the array with for the purposes of the question. The problem is with the iteration and the memory the array occupies. The color pallete does not need to be covered in the answers.

Comment: If you change `$x` and `$y`, how does memory usage change?

Comment: @david: 100x100=0.04591s/1.31Mb/131bytes per pixel

Comment: 300x300=0.37025s/8.91Mb/99bytes per pixel

Comment: 600x600=1.53566s/33.82Mb/94bytes per pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) instead of your direct colour assignment:

```
function createcolor($pic,$c1,$c2,$c3) {
   $color = imagecolorexact($pic, $c1, $c2, $c3);
   if($color==-1) {
      if(imagecolorstotal($pic)>=1000) {
         $color = imagecolorclosest($pic, $c1, $c2, $c3);
      } else {
         $color = imagecolorallocate($pic, $c1, $c2, $c3);
      }
   }
   return $color;
 }
```

Also, try making the function call in 1 line:

```
$ia[$i][$j] = createcolor($im, mt_rand(0,96), mt_rand(0,128), mt_rand(0,255));
```

Fiddle with the hardcoded value 1000, and see how it changes memory usage.

Comment: This will be even slower (and it's not equivalent), but it will consume less memory.

Comment: @Alix, I figured it's worth a try because it might impact only slightly on speed but reduce memory consumption by a greater factor, although the OP hasn't commented, so it's all just speculation... It isn't equivalent, although if the memory saved is large it might be worth losing palette size.

Comment: Indeed, I misinterpreted your code. This is pretty much my answer except that it doesn't require (another) huge array, +1!

Answer (score 3):

Your function is doing a quarter of a million iterations total, that's always going to be rather a lot of a PHP script to be doing.

However, there are things you can do.

First, mt_rand() is faster than rand(), use that instead.

Secondly, you could possibly get some speed increase if you use loop unrolling on the inner loop.  I'm not sure how effective that would actually be in PHP but you can benchmark it to see how effective it is.

```
for ($j=0;$j<$y;$j+=10) {
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 1]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 2]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 3]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 4]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 5]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 6]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 7]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 8]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
    $r=mt_rand(0,96);
    $g=mt_rand(0,128);
    $b=mt_rand(0,255);
    $ia[$i][$j + 9]=ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b);
}
```

However, neither of these will reduce the memory footprint because the data structure you are building is fundamentally a big one.

Maybe you are looking at this problem from the wrong direction?  The first thing you should really be asking yourself here is, do you really need such a huge data structure to accomplish what it is you want to do?  Loop unrolling and using a faster random number generator will get you some performance boost, but in the end the fastest code you can have is code you don't write.  The biggest factor in performance of any given algorithm is always choice of algorithm.  If you rethink what it is that you want to do, you might come up with something that is a lot less wasteful of your computer's memory and processing resources.

Comment: Firstly, I think you meant the loop increment to be `$j += 10`. Secondly, instead of unwinding with a big ugly hardcode (which itself can lower performance), it would probably have the same running time to have just 1 variable with some modulus arithmetic and keep the loop body the original 4 lines. I doubt both of those techniques together will change the running time by any noticeable amount though...

Comment: Each PHP variable takes 68 bytes minimum. Since you're using a two-dimensional array, you are causing `x*y*68` bytes (in your case 500*500*68 = 17 MB) of memory consumption just to store the array. Operating on a bitmap directly would be more memory efficient.

Comment: seems this increases the time and the memory use is the same, btw: the code is already optimized since v1.0. The intent is to create larger images and that would eat up a HUGE amount of mem, so... seeking other options

Comment: @davin: yes, spotted that and fixed it.  And you're probably right about the suggested changes not having much effect, but I did also make the point that choice of algorithm is the most important factor.  @jmz it's really 68 bytes per variable?  Wow.  @alix: It's a technique called loop unrolling, often used in other languages to get more performance out of a loop, though I don't know how effective it would be to do that in PHP. It was pretty much shooting from the hip, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it seems that [imagecreatetruecolor](http://www.graphic-forums.com/archive/index.php/t-2589.html) is probably the most likely culprit for being the memory hog.

Could you use another method, like `imagecreate`, to create an image instead?

Comment: Allocating 250.000 colors in an array will *probably* also eat a *little* memory...

Answer (score 1):

The only improvement I can see in your code is not allocating the same color more than once (in your case `3.203.328` colors for `500.000` pixels), which *should* reduce your memory footprint:

```
$x = 500;
$y = 500;

$image = ImageCreateTrueColor($x, $y);
$matrix = array();
$colors = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $y; $j++)
    {
        $rand = array(rand(0, 96), rand(0, 128), rand(0, 255));

        if (isset($colors[implode('|', $rand)]) !== true)
        {
            $colors[implode('|', $rand)] = ImageColorAllocate($im, $rand[0], $rand[1], $rand[2]);
        }

        $ia[$i][$j] = $colors[implode('|', $rand)];
    }
}
```

Also, if you don't need a true color image `ImageCreate()` should be less of a memory hog.

---

I'm not sure what you're trying to archive but maybe [you would be better with `mt_rand()`](http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/) instead:

[image: rand()]
[image: mt_rand()]